# Using UIView (Singleton) on different viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a UIView which have a button and some view to indicate sucess and failure. I am trying to use that UIView on other view controllers and receive the button action on called view controllers.

This is what i have tried so far

```
protocol FailViewDelegate: class {
    func tryAgainTapped()
}

class AlertView: UIView {

    static let instance = AlertView()


    weak var delegate : FailViewDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashIMageView: AnimatableImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: AnimatableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var iconStatus: AnimatableImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tryAgainButton: AnimatableButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var parentView: UIView!



    private override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }


    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
    }

    enum AlertType {
        case success
        case failure
    }

    func showAlert(alertType: AlertType, to: UIViewController) {
        switch alertType {
        case .success:
            dashIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle-dash-blue")
            circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#4EBFFF")
            titleLbl.text = "Success"
            titleLbl.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#4EBFFF")
            messageLbl.text = "Your ticket has been created."
            tryAgainButton.isHidden = true
            iconStatus.image = UIImage(named: "icon-check")

        case .failure:
            dashIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle-dash-red")
            circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#EB3708")
            titleLbl.text = "Failure"
            titleLbl.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#EB3708")
            messageLbl.text = "There was an error, creating your ticket."
            tryAgainButton.isHidden = false
            iconStatus.image = UIImage(named: "icon-close")
        }

        parentView.center = to.view.center
        to.view.addSubview(parentView)

    }

    func dismissAlert() {
        parentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    @IBAction func tryAgainButtonTapped(_ sender: AnimatableButton) {
        delegate?.tryAgainTapped()
    }


}
```

This is how i have called the view

```
class CreateTicketViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        AlertView.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }





    @IBAction func createTicketTapped(_ sender: AnimatableButton) {
        AlertView.sharedInstance.showAlert(alertType: .failure, to: self)

    }
}

extension CreateTicketViewController : FailViewDelegate {
    func tryAgainTapped() {
        print("Try Again Tapped")

    }

}
```

This is the error that i got

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

(in dashIMageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle-dash-red")) and when i remove the dashImageView then the error occur for nextView and so on

Comment: You have a singleton view?  Why?

Comment: Connect all `outlets` in `xib/storyboard`

Comment: @trojanfoe i want to use same view in multiple controller.

Comment: @Kamran all outlets are connected :)

Comment: @DeependraDhakal  Well you can't.

Comment: @trojanfoe tell me the way to do this

Comment: Do what?  If you want a singleton *state* it just means you do that lower down than the view-level.

Comment: @trojanfoe i want to show the view with one line code and dismiss it with one line like as other custom library popup. Let me know how can i achieve this

Comment: You can't have a singleton `UIView`. You need to create a new instance of your object each time you need one. Just replace `AlertView.sharedInstance` with `AlertView()`

Comment: @Paulw11 whenever i comment  AlertView.sharedInstance.delegate = self then the view is shown but i also need action back to the viewcontroller

Comment: Just assign your new instance of your alert view to a variable so that you can assign the delegate and then show it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make it a singleton, which in this case (View) is a very uncommon approach, I think. You can create as many instances of that view as you want any time, anywhere (on other ViewControllers) you want and specify them, the way you want them to have.

When you want a view to be rendered and be visible, it always must be part of the view hierarchy in the current visible view controllers main view. And a view can only have **ONE SUPERVIEW at the time**, so whenever you add a (singleton) view to another superview, it will be removed from an other superview. If you want the same view on many view controllers (no problem), just don't let it be a singleton.

So first thing to do -> Remove the singleton design by commenting out that line:

```
class AlertView: UIView {

// make this line a comment or just remove it
// static let instance = AlertView()


weak var delegate : FailViewDelegate?
```

In your different view controllers you just create that instances of your AlertView and set the delegate correctly like this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    myAlertView = AlertView()
    myAlertView.delegate = self

    // then you don't need this anymore
    // AlertView.sharedInstance.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: whenever i comment AlertView.sharedInstance.delegate = self then the view is shown but i also need action of try again button back to the viewcontroller

Comment: You have to set the delegate (FailViewDelegate) for every newly created instance of your view to your viewcontroller, to let that viewcontroller being informed about the tap.

Comment: I have added some code to my answer to demonstrate the point.

Comment: whenever i do that it again gives me previous error i.e. Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Which line of your code is marked, when you get the error, so what property or variable is implicitly unwrapped?